# Can't run any git commands in $GERRIT_SITE/git folder

Tags: git, gerrit

I have gerrit installed.

When a project is created through the gerrit web UI, the project is reflected in the `$GERRIT_SITE/git` folder.

For instance if a project *trial* is created on gerrit, a `trial.git` folder is created in `$GERRIT_SITE/git` folder.

But when I try to run any `git` commands in `$GERRIT_SITE/git/trial.git` folder such as follows, I get the following error:

```
$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```

I do not know how to go about this and would need some guidance.

Comment: What is your goal? Do not play with the repo on the server, esp. when you Gerrit is running at the same time. This can easily result in data corruption, if you modify the repo and Gerrit does also afterwards.

Comment: I want to run a service which uses the commit-id's of the commits that would've been generated if I could make this .git directory as a working directory for git.  I don't know if that is advisable or possible?

Comment: Okay, I've edited my answer. Hooks might be useful for you. That's the point, when we access the bare repos. But still, maybe there are other options to do what you need, i.e. REST API or SSH Stream Events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is that what you find on disk is a *bare* repository, without a working tree (i.e. the files of a particular branch). This is totally normal for a Git server and you find the same inside the `.git/` directory once you cloned the repository.

EDIT
You can work on the server side with these bare repos, when you specify the repo's path as the argument for the `GIT_DIR` environment variable:

```
GIT_DIR=/var/gerrit/review/git/trial.git/ git log --quiet --pretty=medium
```

This is esp. helpful when using [Gerrit Hooks](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html) to do something, when a new change is merged etc.

Comment: Yes. It did show the same behavior.  I was looking out for a way if possible, to get the same behavior as when a project is cloned into the local machine i.e to initialize git in the directory to make it my working directory. Is that possible?